# Switch a PHP website's git branch depending on URL parameter

Tags: php, laravel, git, npm

Im working on multiple branches (feature branches) and would want to be able to show the client the status of a feature branch without `ssh`ing into the server and manually switching. How do I show the client something depending on the URL parameter? eg: https://example.com?branch=master would show example.com in `master` branch, https://example.com?branch=feature1 would show `feature1` branch instead.

I know I can

1. Check the query parameter and see if this branch is active.
2. Switch then pull when not.

I think this is trivial to implement especially on occasions that a client is trying to access different branches at the same time as it will take some time to switch branches and then run npm to build assets. What would be a better way to show different branches in this manner?

Comment: How about a subdomain?

Comment: That's what Ive been doing. What I'm looking for is to dynamically do it without the need to ssh into the server

Comment: I would deploy two sites on the same server. Your web server should not be dependent on your version control.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something [like this PHP Git interface](https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php) to switch the branch, but you'll likely need to send a subsequent HTTP request for the assets after a short delay to allow your server (e.g. nginx) to see the changes.

```php
require_once('Git.php');

$repo = Git::open('.');
$repo->checkout('some-branch-name');
```

If you do move forward with this approach, avoid passing user input directly into the commands here. I'd recommend a map between the URL parameter and predefined strings that represent each of your branches.